# Несколько результатов из БД, с учётом сортировки

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select, выборка

Имеется таблица book в которой около 50 записей.
Поля таблицы id(int),name(varchar),path(text),lang(int, value = 1,2,3).
lang=1 примерно 18 записей
lang=2 примерно 16 записей
lang=3 примерно 16 записей
Необходимо составить sql запрос, чтобы выбрать 3 книги, первая из которых это случайное число из первых 18 записей, второе это тоже случайное число из вторых 16 записей, и третья соответственно тоже случайное число из последних 16 записей

Что то на подобие такого: 
SELECT * FROM `book` 
            WHERE `lang`=1 ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1 
                                               AND 
            WHERE `lang`=2 ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1
                                               AND 
            WHERE `lang`=3 ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для ваших объемов данных подойдет очень простой запрос:

```
SELECT random_book.*
FROM book
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY RAND()) random_book ON (book.lang = random_book.lang)
GROUP BY random_book.lang
```

**ORDER BY RAND()** - это не быстро на больших обьемах данных.

Comment: Огромная вам благодарность, я не понимаю как работает этот запрос, но он работает именно так как нужно,

Comment: @ДмитрийСмирнов Ну как работает - это несложно. Группировка - она отбирает одну запись из группы. Но при всей простоте есть проблема - выполните этот запрос сотню-другую раз, соберите результаты, и посмотрите, насколько "случайно" выбираются записи.

Comment: И в новых версиях MySQL, где по умолчанию включен only_full_group_by это не заработает

Comment: Гораздо лучше использовать UNION, т.к. в новых версиях mysql/mariadb/percona 3 запроса выполняются параллельно. Плюс расход ресурсов на union гораздо меньше чем на join.

Comment: Да и в целом запрос с union гораздо проще

Comment: @MikhailKonyukhov Только исправьте свой ответ с union что бы он не выдавал синтаксических ошибок при попытке использования

Answer (score 1):

Для ваших объемов:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE lang=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM book WHERE lang=2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM book WHERE lang=3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Для больших объемов используйте min(id), max(id), rand() и математику в where - будет без order by rand

Comment: order by и limit в середине union писать нельзя, они выполняются на весь запрос целиком. необходимо обрамлять каждый из них еще одним select